# How to shorten a long if else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how I can streamline a possible long if else statement.

There are 8 possibilities that can be chosen and for each option 1-8 I want to display a message.

For example this is what works but I know can be writtern much better:

```
if(this.cv == '1'){ 
 console.log('Greater Then 1');
} else
if(this.cv == '2'){
 console.log('Greater Than 2');
}
```

**etc...**

Looking for something a little more dynamic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review - **http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.**

Comment: if you just need a one-one lookup, no need for switch, which is slower than a LUT: console.log({1:'gt one', 2: 'gt two'}[this.cv])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a map:

```
var messages = {
    '1' : 'Greater than 1',
    '2' : 'Greater than 2',
   ....etc
}

console.log(messages[this.cv]);
```

Comment: i couldn't have said it better myself, though i tried... why run many compares in a switch when you can run one name resolution instead?

Comment: @dandavis Internally, this is pretty much what `switch` does, but with a block of statements instead of just a string.

Comment: switch evaluates each case, ex: switch(true), an object does not. bench if in doubt.

Comment: Thanks this really is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

If that is the exact format of your message (for all cases), then you could simply write:

```
console.log('Greater Than ' + this.cv);
```

However, if you need more flexibility with each case, then you can use a `switch` statement as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Use a switch statement:

```
switch(this.cv)
{
case '1':
  console.log('Greater Than 1');
  break;
case '2':
  console.log('Greater Than 2');
  break;
default:
  //executed if no matches are found
}
```

Or a map would work also work well per adeneo's answer, since that is essentially how a switch statement is implemented.  Both are good options for compressing several if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch statement , check this link [**for more details**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

**Genaral Syntax of SWITCH:**

```
switch (expression) {
  case label1:
    statements1
    [break;]
  case label2:
    statements2
    [break;]
  ...
  case labelN:
    statementsN
    [break;]
  default:
    statements_def
    [break;]
}
```

In your case :

```
switch(this.cv) {
case '1':
    console.log("Greater than 1");
    break;
case '2':
    console.log("Greater than 2");
    break;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be significantly shorter than a series of if statements.

Comment: @j08691 While the written code may not be, the executed operations certainly are ;)

Comment: I have to downvote this answer, though, because you've overcomplicated it. `[break;]`... while I understand it as meaning "optional `break;`", others may not.

Comment: well you should talk with mozilla because i just copied the syntax :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `switch` statement was made for.

```
switch(this.cv) {
case '1':
    console.log("Greater than 1");
    break;
case '2':
    console.log("Greater than 2");
    break;
}
```

You can even add a "catch-all" default action:

```
default:
    console.log("I don't know what to do with "+this.cv);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(n)
{
case '1':
  execute code block 1
  break;
case '2':
  execute code block 2
  break;
default:
  code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say create an object that maps the possible values to messages and simply retrieve the message from the map like so:

```
var messages = {'1': 'Greater Then 1',
                '2': 'Greater Than 2'};
console.log(messages[this.cv]);
```

Comment: Careful, you are trying to index the array with a character value, not an integer...

Comment: arrays are indexed by strings, what's the problem?

Comment: They can be... your edit is perhaps a better practice!

Comment: I think it actually would work in the original option, but I agree that what you suggested makes it clearer what it does, especially since you're retrieving it with a string value.

Answer (score 1):

depends sometimes i have many functions to add to various variables ..

in that case i prefer to use something like that.
i create an object with the answers. then i check if the answer exists and execute it.
i prefer that over switch

```
var a={'2':'greater than 2','1':'greater than 1'}
console.log(a[this.cv]?a[this.cv]:'')
```

another way to write this is

```
 var a={'2':'greater than 2','1':'greater than 1'}
 !a[this.cv]||(console.log(a[this.cv]));
```

or if you just have to do a short check i use javascript shorthand.

```
console.log('Greater then '+(a=this.cv,a==1)?1:(a==2)?2:'whatever');
```

or

```
console.log('Greater then '+(this.cv==1?1:2));
```

and in your case a

```
console.log('Greater than '+this.cv);
```

should be enough.