# How to dynamically add drawables to a TextView

Tags: java, android, listview, textview, drawable

I have a listview that displays a list of textviews. I format the said textviews with a  function tha goes something like

```
private void myFunc(TextView tv){
   if(tv.getText.toString().contains("A")){
       tv.setDrawableLeft(R.id.apple);        
   }else if(tv.getText.toString().contains("A")){
       tv.setDrawableLeft(R.id.apple);        
   }else if(tv.getText.toString().contains("B")){
       tv.setDrawableLeft(R.id.ball);        
   }...
   else if(tv.getText.toString().contains("Z")){
       tv.setDrawableLeft(R.id.zebra);        
   }
```

now this is all pseudo, but it works. I have implemented it. However, my problem now is being able to write it in such a way that I would NOT have to go through a million if-else calls just to be able to format my textviews.

Can anyone suggest a way in order for me to make this logic with a much shorter/more elegant way? Any help, comment, suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can use a `HashMap` using your characters as key and the drawables as value

Comment: Maybe you could rename you drawables, so it would have the same name with text. After that you can get their resource id with `getResources().getIdentifier(tv.getText, "drawable", getPackageName());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your drawables the Names of the text you are matching like A.png for apple.

Then, use the below to get its id from name

```
public int getID(String drawableName){
   Resources resources = context.getResources();
   final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", 
   context.getPackageName());
   return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

and simply do,

```
tv.setDrawableLeft(getID(tv.getText.toString()));
```

Hope this helps. (I like @0xDEADC0DE answers as well. :))

Answer (score 0):

how about you use a map:

[Here's a thread that you might find useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616620/how-to-shorten-a-long-if-else-statement)

it's a javascript thread but i'm sure you'll make some use of it-